# How can i print the final output of program in a single line with space in between after using filter of java 8?

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-stream, output

If I provide the input as `pass@123 jes@234 12345 human`.
The output should print as `pass@123 jes@234` in a single line with space in between.
But it is printing as `pass@123jes@234` without any space.
Below is my code.

```java
List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(ans.split(" "));
        
splitList.stream().filter(s -> !s.matches("[0-9]+") && 
    !s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && s.length() > 5)
.collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

I tried to provide `System.out.print` but the output is printed with no spaces in between.

Comment: what point of your code do you think would cause a space to be printed between the elements?

Comment: Side note: there’s no point in performing two regex match operations. Further, it’s more efficient to make the length test first: `.filter(s -> s.length() > 5 && !s.matches("[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+"))`. Further, there’s no need to collect into a `List` when all you’re doing, is a `forEach`. You can do a `forEach` on the Stream in the first place. But as the anwers say, for your actual task, `.collect(Collectors.joining(" "))` is the right tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Collectors.joining`

Here is some helpful Documentation, there are some other useful Collectors as well.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

example code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ans = "pass@123 jes@234 12345 human";

        final String space = " ";
        
        String line = Arrays.stream(ans.split(space))// you can use Arrays.stream directly, without calling Arrays.asList first
            .filter(giveMeSomeMeaningFulName()) //separated into separate method to improve readability
            .collect(Collectors.joining(space));//Collectors.joining join the strings with the provided string as separator

        System.out.println(line);
    }

    private static Predicate<? super String> giveMeSomeMeaningFulName() {
        return s -> !s.matches("[0-9]+") && !s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && s.length() > 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) method. For example:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class JoiningExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ans = "pass@123 jes@234 12345 human";
        List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(ans.split(" "));


        String result = splitList.stream().filter(s -> !s.matches("[0-9]+") &&
                        !s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && s.length() > 5)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        System.out.println(result); // Output: "pass@123 jes@234"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *[Collectors#joining](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence))* method.

Additionally, I am using `\\w&&[^_]` in place of the other two patterns.
And, I figured checking the length before the pattern is more logical.

```java
String input = "pass@123 jes@234 12345 human";
String output
    = Arrays.stream(input.split(" +"))
            .filter(x -> x.length() > 5 && !x.matches("\\w&&[^_]+"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Output

```
pass@123 jes@234
```